# Dial USSD code?

Tags: android

When I dial a directly from the handset it works. For example: *123# gets balance of number.

However, when I try to do the same thing from within an application I get a problem. The number displayed in the dialer is missing the ending #. 
I need it in my application i want my app should support all the USSD codes.

Is there any way to dial ussd codes with in the application?

Comment: any work around for these problem

Comment: can any one has any more answers to do

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm not completely sure but I think USSD is not yet supported on android, however you can try this workaround:

```
String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");
String ussd = "*" + encodedHash + "123" + encodedHash;
startActivityForResult(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL",
Uri.parse("tel:" + ussd)), 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String encodedHash = Uri.encode("*123#");
startActivityForResult(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL",
Uri.parse("tel:" + encodedHash)), 1);
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to include an explanation or any description of the code you shared.