# make network call not working if the number contain #

Tags: android, numbers, call

Hi I am creating an android app to call a network number with this code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String num= "*123#";
    String number = "tel:" + num;
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(number)); 
    startActivity(callIntent);
}
```

but the "#" does not appear in the called number

Comment: see [Dial USSD code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214915/dial-ussd-code) to dial USSD Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's security issue ?

try this:

```
      public void onClick(View v) {
    String num= "*123";
String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");
string last = num + encodedHash;
    String number = "tel:" + last;
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(number)); 
    startActivity(callIntent);
}
```