# Trying to make an android app call a number

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to make the app I am creating open the dialer and send a call using the sequence of characters from the "seq" variable.

I get errors when I try. This is my code.

```
public void sendCall(View v){
    EditText phoneNumberText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.phoneNumberText);
    EditText topUpValueText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.topUpValueText);
    EditText passCodeText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.passCodeText);
    Integer phoneNumber=Integer.parseInt(phoneNumberText.getText().toString()),topUpValue=Integer.parseInt(topUpValueText.getText().toString()),passCode=Integer.parseInt(passCodeText.getText().toString());
    String seq="*195*4000*" + passCode.toString() + "*868" + phoneNumber.toString() + "*" + topUpValue.toString() + "#";
    Uri number = Uri.parse(seq);
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, number);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dial numbers in this format: **"tel:123456789"**

If you want to place the call (ACTION_CALL instead of ACTION_DIAL), you must require this permission:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

In your Manifest file.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The number to be dialed is sequence of characters acquired from the "seq" variable. An example of the sequence would be *195*4000*8685553333*20# how would I send that to "tel:*195*4000*8685553333*20#" ?

Comment: First of, add "tel:" to seq: **seq = "tel:" + seq;**. Then, I'd remove all the GARBAGE CHARS (\*,#). All which is not NUMERIC. **seq = seq.replace("\*", "");** and **seq = seq.replace("#", "");**

Comment: The sequence is a USSD code and needs the (*,#) to work correctly. If it sends the call like this "tel:1954000868555333320", it wont work. I will add add "tel:" to seq though.

Comment: I see. It could work, even if I never tried to make an USSD call before. Tell me what happens - maybe "tel:" isn't the right trick.

Comment: I'll try it. The app will be run on a network called Digicel in the Caribbean. So I assume things work differently than US Carriers.

Comment: Man, you're lucky... It seems to work: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214915/dial-ussd-code)

Answer (score 2):

using  **`Intent.ACTION_DIAL`**:  Dial a number as specified by the data. This shows a UI with the number being dialed, allowing the user to explicitly initiate the call.

```
  public static void callContact(Context context, String contactNumber) {
       try {
     String uri = "tel:" + contactNumber;
     Intent DialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse(uri));
            DialIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(DialIntent);
     } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Using **`Intent.ACTION_CALL`** : Activity Action: Perform a call to someone specified by the data.

```
public static void callContact(Context context, String contactNumber) {
    try {
        String uri = "tel:" + contactNumber;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(uri));
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Add this permission to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

So I have this following utility method [here](https://github.com/midhunhk/ae-apps-library/blob/master/library/AeAppsLibrary/src/com/ae/apps/common/utils/MobileNetworkUtils.java).

```
public static void callContact(Context context, String contactNo) {
    try {
        String uri = "tel:" + contactNo;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Report no exception
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add this as a permission in the manifest
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />`

Comment: Yes, I added the permission to the manifest file. Must I add this to a new block? or can I nest this into public void?

Comment: I have shared a utility method here.